# Which image size's are used for set up image will cover total screen using Image source in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to set the image, which cover full screen width and height. Here I am not able to using 'BackgroundImage' property, because I want to apply 'ScaleTo' property to the images. So need to set the image to images resource. I am using fallowing images sizes for setup the images. 1. 480 * 720 2. 640 * 960 3. 960 * 1440. These are not cover the entire screen in my application, still showing some white space. Pleas suggest what images sizes are suitable for setup images to entire screen.

Comment: Is this for a splash screen? It really depends what device you are using. Android and iOS follow different rules.

Comment: Hi Steve, This is not used for splash screen. I am working on xamarin android project.

Answer (score 1):

Try Application.Current.MainPage.Width and Application.Current.MainPage.Height

Or grab it from Android using a dependency service

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
    var widthInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.WidthPixels);
    var heightInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.HeightPixels);
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, I have tried with fallowing code but I am getting null value from mainpage.height and width.

Comment: You have to wait until the page is loaded.i.e. in OnAppearing

Comment: Or you can use a dependency service and grab it from Android

Comment: Thanks Steve. I am getting device width and height in my main activity but the issue is at first time image is loading slowly from top to bottom(Clearly visible the background) then after it shows full screen.

Comment: Try making the background of the page it is loading over the same color as the majority of the image so it is less noticable.

Comment: Also on Xamarin Android use FFImageLoading to reduce memory usage on resized images https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Comment: I am already using ffimageloading for images. If I set like this also it is visible to the user because little bit flickering in happen in the screen.